# Store items from a list if condition is fulfilled

Tags: python

Python is not getting me any error, but also not the results I want (therefore I also fail to find help in the forum). 
I am trying to get two new arrays F_h and F_n. If item in list data_WL is
larger than 0.5 I would like to have F_n as a counter and F_h to store the values above 0.5. In an overall 9 years i want to have windows of 3 years.

```
data_WL = [0.4001, 0.3966472, 0.4365047, 0.4950109, 0.5348455, 0.5816008, 0.5816009, 0.09, -0.03]
one_year = 3
all_years= 9
data_WL1 = [float(x) for x in data_WL] # convert items to float
print data_WL1

F_h = []
F_n = []
for i in arange(0, all_years - 1 ,1):
    flood = 0
    F_h.append(data_WL[i])

    for j in arange(0, one_year -1,1):
        if data_WL1[j] >= 0.5:
            flood = flood + 1
            F_h.append(float(data_WL1[j])) 
        else:
            flood = flood
        print flood

    F_n.append(flood)

print "Flood frequency"
print F_n
print "Flood magnitude"
print F_h
```

The results should therefore look as such:

```
Flood Frequency
[0,2,1]

Flood magnitude
[0.5348455, 0.5816008, 0.5816009]
```

Comment: `0.4001` is not `>0.5` why F_n has value `0`?

Comment: You might be try this `>>> [x for x in enumerate(data_WL) if x[1] > 0.5]
[(4, 0.5348455), (5, 0.5816008), (6, 0.5816009)]`

Comment: @TimCastelijns I suspect the OP means [numpy.arange](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to give you the desired results:

```
data_WL = [0.4001, 0.3966472, 0.4365047, 0.4950109, 0.5348455, 0.5816008, 0.5816009, 0.09, -0.03]

F_n = [sum(item > 0.5 for item in three) for three in zip(*[iter(data_WL)]*3)]
F_h = [item for item in data_WL if item > 0.5]

print "Flood frequency", F_n
print "Flood magnitude", F_h
```

This displays:

```
Flood frequency [0, 2, 1]
Flood magnitude [0.5348455, 0.5816008, 0.5816009]
```

It uses the `grouper` [recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) to read three years at a time and sum the values in each group that are above `0.5`.

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to upvote any answers you found useful, and you can then click on the tick next to one of them to accept the solution.

Comment: Great solution implemented in python!

Answer (score 0):

As per my understandin, this might be give you what u want

```
>>> [x for x in enumerate(data_WL) if x[1] > 0.5]
[(4, 0.5348455), (5, 0.5816008), (6, 0.5816009)]
>>> F_n, F_h = zip(*[x for x in enumerate(data_WL) if x[1] > 0.5])
>>> F_n
(4, 5, 6)
>>> F_h
(0.5348455, 0.5816008, 0.5816009)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood OP's question, the conditional "count" should be in 3-year windows, yours is performing in a rolling basis. [0, 2, 1] & [4, 5, 6]. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem come from you "j". If you add:

```
print "j = " + str(j)
```

You will see it stays at 1. So, you can not enter in your IF statement because you are only comparing the first value "0.4001".

```
for j in arange(0, one_year-1, 1):
```

Has to be:

```
for j in arange(0, all_years-1, 1):
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're probably using **numpy** (with `arange`) , here is one alternative to achieve what you want:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: data_WL = [0.4001, 0.3966472, 0.4365047, 0.4950109, 0.5348455, 0.5816008, 0.5816009, 0.09, -0.03]

# construct a numpy array with float type
In [3]: WL = np.array(data_WL).astype(float)

# split the array into 3-year period window
# ie. 9 years, 3 years period
In [4]: WL_3 = np.split(WL, 9/3)

# Perform a sum (as count) on each window if condition is met
In [5]: F_n = [sum(wl > 0.5) for wl in WL_3]

# masking and return the list of values where condition is met
In [6]: F_h = WL[WL > 0.5].tolist()
```

Results:

```
In [7]: F_n
Out[7]: [0, 2, 1]

In [8]: F_h
Out[8]: [0.5348455, 0.5816008, 0.5816009]
```

Probably not the best implementation but it is surely one way to do it.

Comment: And something perfectly understandable, thanks for the help

Comment: @Laura, always glad to help others :-) if you want Python's implementation, other answers are much better and less overheads. But if you want to go with numpy (I do suggest), this would be a good starting point.